# R incorrectly identifies numeric values as a date and converting it to numeric results in large negative values

Tags: r

I'm importing a large number of excel files into R using lapply but for a few columns with values, R seems to recognize them as a date column. For example, 7.5 was recognized as 1900-01-07 12:00:00. There are several columns where R does this. Using

```
as.numeric
```

on the column results in "-2208427200"

Is there any way to make sure the columns on the 50+ excel files that I import are have the correct structure

Edit: This is the code I'm using to import the data

```
    temp = list.files(pattern="*.XLSX")
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.XLSX$", "", temp))), col_names=FALSE,read_excel,skip=2), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

There's 50-53 variables per file. I'm importing with the first two rows as headers. I'm skipping the first two rows and will later rename each file.

The data I'm importing looks kind of like this but I'm dealing with many more variables

```
Name File# Date   Rate Hours TempRate 
BOB  101   5/9/19  $20  7.5   $18
ROB  102   5/10/19 $30  0     $20
Nick 103   5/10/19 30   7     $40
```

Comment: Please include a MWE so others can replicate. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide the code that you used to import the data including any libraries that you used.